# FindbyUsername always returns undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, passport-local

I am trying to implement logging in and logging out with passport local strategy. The strategy is to run a function to check if a user with that username exists, then proceed to use passport and bcrypt to log in.
Every other thing works except the post route for loggin in

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    const user = du.findByUsername;

    if (!user) {
      console.log("user does not exist");
      return done(null, false, { message: "user does not exist" });
    }

    const match = bcrypt.compare(password, user.pword);
    
    if(!match) {
      console.log("Incorrect password");
      return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
    }
    
    console.log("success");
    
    return done(null, user);
  })
);
```

Routes:

```
router.post(
  ["/users/login", "/users/:id"],
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/users/login",
  }),

  // redirect to see all prdoucts upon login
  db.getAllProducts
);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the findbyUsername that always retruns undefined
Note that in the database, the password is stored in the pword column

```
const findByUsername = (name) => {
  pool.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1",
    [name],
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      return results.rows;
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: You've defined `findByUsername` as a function; you set `user` to a **reference** to that function instead of calling the function. Once you've fixed that your next issue will dupe [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992).

Comment: Thanks. I adjusted it. But it still returns undefined. I even added username and password fields to specify what the username is

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to see your adjustments. It’s still likely to be related to the link I posted previously.